# JQuery Same Height DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to this so I think I am missing something simple.

You can see it [here](http://www.guygar.com/inception/nothingness/index.html).

As you can see from the message boxes the JavaScript is working fine but the two DIVs are not being resized to the same height.

The JavaScript I am using is this:

```
function doResize() {
    alert('before: being ' + $('#being').height());
    alert('before: questions ' + $('#questions').height());
    maxHeight = 0;
    var divs = jQuery("#questions, #being");
    $.each(divs, function () {
        var height = jQuery(this).height();
        if (maxHeight < height) maxHeight = height;
    });
    divs.height(maxHeight);
    alert('after: being ' + $('#being').height());
    alert('after: questions ' + $('#questions').height());
    $("#main").css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```

I call this function on document onload event.

Please guide me because this code is working on other pages!

best regards!

EDIT (here is the corrected code):

```
function doResize()
{

    //alert('before: being ' + $('#beingContent').height());

    //alert('before: questions ' + $('#questionsContent').height());

    maxHeight = 0;

    var divs = jQuery("#questionsContent, #beingContent");

    $.each(divs, function(){
        var height = jQuery(this).height();
            if(maxHeight<height)
                maxHeight = height;
    });

    divs.height(maxHeight);

    $('#beingContent').css('height', maxHeight - 2);

    //alert('after: being ' + $('#beingContent').height());

    //alert('after: questions ' + $('#questionsContent').height());


    $("#root").css('visibility', 'visible');

}
```

and the CSS:

```
#beingContent { padding:0 5px !important; border:1px solid black !important ;}
```

That solved the alignment issue! Thanks.

Comment: they have the same height this works fine but you've added `padding:5px` to div `#being` and this is problem if you use `padding: 0 5px` it'll looks ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

```css
#being {
   padding:0 5px !important;
}
```

---

div with `being` has `padding :5px` so top and bottom gets `5px` extra each which create a different so instead of `padding :5px` just assign padding to left and right .

Comment: @AgentSmith `#being {
   padding:0 5px !important;
}` try with !important to override inline style .

Comment: Almost! But still not the same size. different browsers render differently as well.

Comment: @AgentSmith `#being { padding:0 5px !important; border:0 !important ;}` Working in all browser checked .

Comment: I need the black border! made an modification so its runs on safari, chrome and firefox. but in IE11 it does not size up!

Comment: @AgentSmith `height=height+padding-bottom+padding-top+border-top+border-bottom` .

Comment: please explain. height+padding... I am using question div to calculate this in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Remove borders/padding from css;
or use [this](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) for the win. :)

Cuz I'm lazy too, just add this to your stylesheet:

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
```